# QGIS Modeler algorithm does not accept input variable

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I am trying to make a QGIS model which includes an "Extract by Attribute" algorithm. One of the inputs for this function is the liminar value, simply called "Value". For some reason though, it is only possible to explicitly state that value, and not use a number variable that was inserted into the model.

Is this behaviour as expected or a bug? Is there a work around?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **Extract by attribute** tool from the modeler accepts **String** inputs, **not Number** inputs. Here's a simple test which uses the following input parameters:

- Input - Table Field
- Layer - Vector layer
- Value - String *(with default value of 80)*

[image: Modeler]

Now when I run this, the default value will show up automatically:

[image: Running the modeler]

I have tested this on various field attributes (integer, real etc.) and it works great! Hope this helps!

Comment: Perfect! Although I still disagree with QGIS developers! Doesn't make too much sense.

Comment: @jhc - Awesome, glad it works buddy! Haha, well the _String_ parameter does allow for text aswell as numbers in attributes so it makes sense to me but it's personal opinion :)